# Configure buffer display name to show directory when buffer name is short

Tags: buffers

I don't normally `set autochdir`, but I'm trying it out and seeing what kind of small frustrations I encounter as a way of learning more about vim.

For the purposes of this question, my `.vimrc` is the following:

```
set laststatus=2
set autochdir
```

Suppose I'm working with the following project.

```
~/tmp/some-project $ tree
.
├── a
│   └── README.txt
└── b
    └── README.txt
```

If I run the following, then `emacs` will populate two buffers that display as `README.txt<a>` and `README.txt<b>`.

```
emacs `find . -type f`
```

If I run the following, then `vim` will create two buffers side by side.

```
vim -O `find . -type f`
```

One of the buffers will be called `README.txt` and the other will be called `~/tmp/some-project/b/README.txt`.

When I change which buffer has focus, then the names will all shift because `vim` itself has `chdir`ed when `autochdir` is set.

---

The problem that I'm running into is this. If I only have one buffer visible, then that buffer will be called `README.txt` regardless of which directory I'm in and I can't tell which `README.txt` I'm looking at.

Is there a way to configure vim to show buffers with single-segment paths as `README.txt<a>` or something similar so I can more easily tell which file I'm editing when `autochdir` is enabled.

Comment: You can personalize your status line with `:help 'statusline'` and massage filenames with `:help fnamemodify()`. Also, `autochdir` is an abomination.

Comment: I prefer to have the Vim working directory to be set to the root of the project (`~/tmp/some-project`). There are plugins that do that for you automatically based on the content of the root folder (e.g. [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter)).

Comment: Funny to read such strong feelings on `autochdir`. I've had it enabled for ten years or so and I actually like it. Having it off tends to confuse me. When in doubt, ask `:pwd`. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, or run `:file`
- Configure your statusline

For the statusline, you can experiment with `%f` (in the default), `%F`, and `%t`. I’ve [rolled my own](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/42e735921210a6bc6da3932c0d88d54db613693e/links/vim/vimrc#L192-L217) such that I can switch been short statusline (`%t`) and long statusline (path + `%t`), where the trailing component is always highlighted.